# Axis2 SocketTimeoutException: Read Time Out

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying the build a SOAP client to access the National Weather Service NDFD SOAP Service. I'm using Axis2 1.6.2 with code generated with wsdl2java.

Every time I try to retrieve data, I receive a AxisFault saying Read timed out. 
I have tried to increase the timeout time to up to 500 s, but all that does is make it wait longer before giving the same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: [was class java.net.SocketTimeoutException] Read timed out
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at gov.weather.graphical.xml.dwmlgen.wsdl.ndfdxml_wsdl.NdfdXMLStub.fromOM(NdfdXMLStub.java:26499)
at gov.weather.graphical.xml.dwmlgen.wsdl.ndfdxml_wsdl.NdfdXMLStub.nDFDgen(NdfdXMLStub.java:595)
at he.andrew.ndfd.NDFDData.getData(NDFDData.java:47)
at he.andrew.ndfd.NDFDData.main(NDFDData.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [was class java.net.SocketTimeoutException] Read timed out
at com.ctc.wstx.util.ExceptionUtil.throwRuntimeException(ExceptionUtil.java:18)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:731)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3657)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getText(BasicStreamReader.java:809)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getElementText(BasicStreamReader.java:679)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:100)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:100)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.SwitchingWrapper.getElementText(SwitchingWrapper.java:936)
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.getElementText(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:100)
at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.debug.XMLStreamReaderValidator.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderValidator.java:75)
at gov.weather.graphical.xml.dwmlgen.wsdl.ndfdxml_wsdl.NdfdXMLStub$NDFDgenResponse$Factory.parse(NdfdXMLStub.java:5612)
at gov.weather.graphical.xml.dwmlgen.wsdl.ndfdxml_wsdl.NdfdXMLStub.fromOM(NdfdXMLStub.java:26353)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.WireLogInputStream.read(WireLogInputStream.java:69)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:182)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInputStream.java:108)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
... more not included
```

The error seems to be the same as the one here: [Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412254/exception-in-thread-main-org-apache-axis2-axisfault-read-timed-out). However, I don't quite understand any of the responses to that question.

One final note. In order to avoid a "411 Error: Length Required", I had to turn off the Chunked option. I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: "Read timed out" means the remote service didn't return a response to your request, and your client eventually gave up waiting. I don't know if anyone could tell you specifically what is wrong with this service, beyond the fact that it's unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error on a project, and the root cause was a proxy server setting.  I had to modify the proxy to allow the communication to the service I was trying to hit.  My code was running as part of a custom application that used its own proxy.  So this may also be something to try.